# remove records which have less than 95 percentile value counts

Tags: python

I want to remove all those records whose value counts is less than 95 percentile. I am presently doing this statically for value counts <=5 but I want to keep only the top 95 percentile of the value counts. How should I get that? Also the PART_NO here is categorical.

```
vc = repair['PART_NO'].value_counts()
u  = [i not in set(vc[vc<=5].index) for i in repair['PART_NO']]
repair = repair[u]
repair.describe(include="all")
```

Comment: use >= 95 istead of <= 5?

Comment: Can you give you question more clear?

Comment: I do not want >=95 I need to get the percentile of how each part_no is distributed and preserve the top 95% and drop the remaining. @Julien

Comment: @Jayhello I hope my previous comment makes it a little more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking to keep the 95th percentile not the percentage.
Hence the solution is:

## get the frequency of each part number and add it to the dataframe

`repair['FREQ'] = \
    repair.groupby('PART_NO', as_index=False)['PART_NO'].transform(lambda s: s.count())
repair.head()`

## filter out rows of repair where repair.freq is greater than or equal to the 95th percentile: 19600

`repair = repair[repair.FREQ < repair.FREQ.quantile(.95)]`

Answer (score 0):

May be I have understand you questions wrong, Let's give a example. As the below code:

```
# in the below list, the num 1 have percentile > 95
lst = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
count = len(lst) * 1.0

# test for each num percentile compute
print [[x, lst.count(x) / count] for x in set(lst)]
# [[1, 0.9545454545454546], [2, 0.045454545454545456]]

# remove percentile < 95
ret_lst = [[x, lst.count(x) / count] for x in set(lst) if lst.count(x) / count >= 0.95]
print ret_lst
# [[1, 0.9545454545454546]]

# get the item whose percentile > 95
lst_final = [item[0] for item in ret_lst]
print lst_final
# [1]
```

The elements in the above `lst` can be `str` or other `type`.For example:

```
# the lst can have any type, like int, str in the below
# in the below list, the 'a' have percentile > 95
lst = ['a', 'b', 1, 0, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
       'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
       'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
       'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
       'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
       'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
       'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
       'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
       'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']

count = len(lst) * 1.0

# test for each elements percentile compute
print [[x, lst.count(x) / count] for x in set(lst)]
# [['a', 0.9508196721311475], [1, 0.01639344262295082], ['b', 0.01639344262295082], [0, 0.01639344262295082]]

# remove percentile < 95
ret_lst = [[x, lst.count(x) / count] for x in set(lst) if lst.count(x) / count >= 0.95]
print ret_lst
# [['a', 0.9508196721311475]]

lst_final = [item[0] for item in ret_lst]
print lst_final
# ['a']
```

Comment: yes I would say I am looking to do this but the problem is the list that you are using here has int data type but my column PART_NO has categorical values which cannot be converted to int unless encoded.

Comment: #Part_No column to a list. 
`vc =repair['PART_NO'].tolist()
count = len(vc) * 1.0`. 

# test for each num percentile compute. 
`print [[x, vc.count(x) / count] for x in set(vc)]`. This gives me something like this which doesn't show the percentage. What am I missing? [['MY661-03509', 1.4469665070662609e-06], ['661-7031', 7.234832535331305e-06], ['661-01463', 7.234832535331304e-07], ['661-01460', 7.234832535331304e-07]

Comment: so here my list PART_NO has values like these ['KH661-05782',
 'ZD661-05428',
 'CH661-04581',
 '661-07970',
 '661-07299'] @jayhello

Comment: There is nothing to do with the type of value in lst.

For example 'KH661-05782' is equivalent to the above 'a'  in lst. For example, I add the value to the lst. I get: 
[['a', 0.90625], [1, 0.015625], ['b', 0.015625], [0, 0.015625], ['CH661-04581', 0.015625], ['KH661-05782', 0.015625], ['ZD661-05428', 0.015625]]
The percentage of  'CH661-04581' is 0.015625.

Comment: @Sayonti , does the above solve you problem? If it does, can you accept the answer?

Comment: for some reason when I am inserting the part_no column from my DataFrame to a list and computing the percentage on it the output is not correct and not in order too. I do not know how to fix it so your solution is still not working for me.

Comment: I have taken the part_no column and made a python list:  
`#Part_No column to a list
vc =repair['PART_NO'].tolist()
count = len(vc) * 1.0`. 
Now 
`# test for each num percentile compute
for i in repair['PART_NO']:
    print([i,vc.count(i)/count])`
Now I want to the percentile less than 95 but I get error in it. Please help.

`# remove percentile < 95
for i in repair['PART_NO']:
    if (vc.count(i)/count >=0.95)
        remove=[i,vc.count(i)/count]
        print remove`